# Industrial recycling of mirrors

Tags: metals

I learned recently that mirror is mostly manufactured by pouring thin metal coating (i.e alumunium) on top of a substrate surface (i.e glass),

Due to the nature of this composition it cannot be easily disposed. I searched everywhere on how to recycle mirror and it always end up suggesting to recycle it physically (i.e artwork props etc).

Assuming on industrial level mirror waste, how its getting recycled? I found no machine in market to do so. And it seems melting them to recover the glass & aluminum isn't the answer either

What then would be the best way to make use mirror waste in tonnage batches weekly?

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the question "Is this being done?" or is it "Could this possibly be done?"

Comment: Have you considered the fraction of aluminum metal in this weekly "tonnage" of mirror scrap?  The Al is not poured;  it is vapor deposited...